# I have a problem with transactions in my Spring Boot - I got an exceptio, but transaction is commiting

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, transactions

I have problem with transaction support in my Spring Boot application. I got and exception if function dodajRezerwacje(), but records in database are changed.

I verified all services and they have @Transactional annotation. I added "springframework.transaction=DEBUG" to application.properties to find a problem, but I didn't.

App.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "ekoncept.dao")
@ComponentScan(value = "ekoncept.*")
@EntityScan("ekoncept.model.entity")
@EnableScheduling
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

EntityManagerFactoriesConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
public class EntityManagerFactoriesConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
        emf.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[]{"ekoncept"});             // czy cały pakiet?? nie wiem...
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(
                new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        return emf;
    }
}
```

TransactionManagersConfig.java:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionManagersConfig {
    @Autowired
    EntityManagerFactory emf;
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager tm =
                new JpaTransactionManager();
        tm.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        tm.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return tm;
    }
}
```

RezerwacjaManager.java:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class RezerwacjaManager {
...
public boolean edytujRezerwacje(String input, AuthUser user)
            throws IOException, RecordIdNotFoundException, ParamValueNotValidException, ParseException, RecordIdNotAllowedException,
            RecordNotExistsException, MethodParamMissingException, RequiredFieldNotFoundException,
            CCardNotModificableException, OnlinePaymentErrorException {

        logMgr.logJsonInput("edytujRezerwacje", input);

        Rezerwacja rez = (Rezerwacja) rezFact.getUpdatedObject(input);
        org.json.JSONObject jsonObj = new org.json.JSONObject(input);

        if (jsonObj.has("CCard")) {     // THIS OPERATIONS ARE SAVED IN DB  (insert into table CCard + delete from tabele Ccard + update table Rezerwacja)                                           
            Ccard oldCC = null;
            if (rez.getCcardId() != null) {    // karta została już wprowadzona
                oldCC = ccardDao.findOne(rez.getCcardId());
                if (oldCC != null && oldCC.getCcardVerified() == 1) {
                    throw new CCardNotModificableException("karta została zweryfikowana");
                }
            }
            String ccNumer = "";
            org.json.JSONObject ccObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("CCard");
            Ccard cc = (Ccard) ccardFact.getNewObject(ccObj.toString());
            ccardDao.save(cc);
            histMgr.logToHistoryCCard(cc.getCcardId(), rez.getRezerwacjaId(), null, user, Operacja.NOWY_REKORD);

            if (oldCC != null) {                             // usunięcie starych danych
                histMgr.logToHistoryCCard(oldCC.getCcardId(), rez.getRezerwacjaId(), null, user, Operacja.USUNIECIE_DANYCH);
                ccardDao.delete(oldCC);
            }
            rez.setCcardId(cc.getCcardId());
        }

        if (jsonObj.has("Platonline")) {   // NOT EXECUTING IN THIS CASE
            ....
        }

        rezDao.save(rez);                                               // THIS OPERATIONS ARE SAVED IN DB (update table Rezerwacja)  
        histMgr.logToHistory(rez, user, Operacja.MODYFIKACJA_DANYCH);   // THIS OPERATIONS ARE SAVED IN DB (insert into table Historiaop)

        if (jsonObj.has("Rezerwacjaosoba")) {
            ....
        }
        if (jsonObj.has("Usluga")) {
            ....                        // !!! HERE I GOT AN EXCEPTION !!!
        }
        return true;
    }
...
}
```

My DEBUG.log:

```
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4869f607
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Creating new transaction with name [ekoncept.service.RezerwacjaManager.edytujRezerwacje]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@3896d31d]
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - select ... from Rezerwacja rezerwacja0_ where rezerwacja0_.REZERWACJA_ID=?
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - select ... from Pokoj pokoj0_ where pokoj0_.POKOJ_ID=?
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - select ... from Pokojtyp pokojtyp0_ where pokojtyp0_.POKOJTYP_ID=?
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - select ... from Asort asort0_ where asort0_.ASORT_ID=?
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - select ... from OSOBA osoba0_ where osoba0_.OSOBA_ID=?
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - select ... from Usluga usluga0_ where usluga0_.USLUGA_DOMYSLNA=-1 and (usluga0_.REZERWACJA_ID=? or ? is null) and (usluga0_.MELDUNEK_ID=? or ? is null)
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[ekoncept.model.entity.Rezerwacja#81997], EntityKey[ekoncept.model.entity.Pokoj#-3], EntityKey[ekoncept.model.entity.Pokojtyp#3], EntityKey[ekoncept.model.entity.Osoba#35054], EntityKey[ekoncept.model.entity.Asort#24]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - select ... from Ccard ccard0_ where ccard0_.CCARD_ID=?
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - select gen_id( SEQ_CCARD, 1 ) from RDB$DATABASE
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=1} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=1} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=1} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=1} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - select gen_id( SEQ_HISTORIAOP, 1 ) from RDB$DATABASE
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=2} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=2} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=2} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=2} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - select gen_id( SEQ_HISTORIAOP, 1 ) from RDB$DATABASE
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=3} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=3} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=1} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=3} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=1} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=3} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=1} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - select gen_id( SEQ_HISTORIAOP, 1 ) from RDB$DATABASE
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=4} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=1} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - select rezerwacja0_.OSOBA_ID as OSOBA_ID1_148_, rezerwacja0_.REZERWACJA_ID as REZERWAC2_148_ from Rezerwacjaosoba rezerwacja0_ where rezerwacja0_.REZERWACJA_ID=?
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=4} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=1} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=4} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=1} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - select ... from Rezerwacjaosoba rezerwacja0_ where rezerwacja0_.REZERWACJA_ID=? and rezerwacja0_.OSOBA_ID=?
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=4} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=1} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=4} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=1} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - select ... from Usluga usluga0_ where usluga0_.REZERWACJA_ID=?
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=4} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=1} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - select ... from Usluga usluga0_ where usluga0_.USLUGA_ID=?
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Initiating transaction commit
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[...],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=4} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=1} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - insert into Ccard ...
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - insert into Historiaop ...
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - insert into Historiaop ...
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - insert into Historiaop ...
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - update Rezerwacja set ... where REZERWACJA_ID=?
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - delete from Ccard where CCARD_ID=?
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Closing JPA EntityManager
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4869f607
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2019-01-09 12:54:48 - Closing JPA EntityManager
```

I got an exception in 294 line (I do it with premeditation to check transaction, it's not a bug) and data is saved/updated in tables Rezerwacja, CCard and Historiaop. 
When exception occured in this method I want transaction to be rolled back.

Comment: What type of exception you have in line 294?Can you paste your code for line 294?

Comment: What is the reason you are working around instead of with spring Boot? Spring Boot can do all the configuration for you instead of manually configuring things. Start with cleaning things up I would say. Also are you by any change using MySQL then make sure you are using tables that support transactions like InnoDB and not of the MyISAM type which don't support transactions.

Comment: @M.Deinum So, if I comment out my entityManagerFactory bean and my transactionManager bean transactions in hibernate will still work?

Comment: Yes, the same applies to all the annotations on the `App` class. It should be in the `ekoncept` package and you can then remove all annotations but `@SpringBootApplication` and `@EnableScheduling`.

Answer (score 4):

@Transactional only rolls back transactions for unchecked exceptions.
if you throw an Exception or a subclass of it and you want to rollback if a checked exception occurs then use this

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

So on top of the method

```
public boolean edytujRezerwacje(String input, AuthUser user)
            throws IOException, RecordIdNotFoundException, ParamValueNotValidException, ParseException, RecordIdNotAllowedException,
            RecordNotExistsException, MethodParamMissingException, RequiredFieldNotFoundException,
            CCardNotModificableException, OnlinePaymentErrorException {
```

add the following

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. You've wrote that I should add annotation at top of the method. Now I use annotations at top of classes, which one is better practise? Or maybe I should use @Transactional(readOnly=true) annotation on top of classes and @Transactional(readOnly=false,  rollbackFor = Exception.class) on top of methods which are modifing database?

Answer (score 2):

Its always good practice to have method level @Transactional annotation for ease of troubleshooting and maintainability of the code.
Rollback happens only when the application throws a unchecked exception.
Adding : `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)`  on top of your method will allow you to trigger a rollback.

Comment: Thanks for advice. So, should I use @Transactional(readOnly=true) annotation on top of classes and @Transactional(readOnly=false, rollbackFor = Exception.class) on top of methods which are modifing database? I understand it right?